# Mocha not showing chai expect error messages

Tags: node.js, testing, mocha.js, chai, ecmascript-2017

I'm using Mocha and Chai + ChaiHttp for testing my API. The problem I have is that I don't see any error messages when a `expect` statement is failing.

Here is my code:

```
it('POST /signup : should create a new user', async () => {
  const user = {
    name: 'Felix',
    email: 'felix@gmail.com',
    password: 'test',
  };

  const res = await chai.request(app).post('/signup').send(user);

  expect(res).to.be.json;
  expect(res).to.have.status(200);
  expect(res.body).to.be.an('object');
  expect(res.body.success).to.equal(true);
  expect(res.body.user).to.have.property('falseAttribute'); // <- test passes with "name"
  expect(res.body.user).to.have.property('token');
});
```

When it fails because the returned use is expected to have the `falseAttribute`, it simply shows me the 'it' text highlighted in red:

```
  Authentication tests
    1) POST /signup : should create a new user`)
```

In my package.json scripts I put `"test": "NODE_ENV=test ./node_modules/.bin/mocha test"`

I've already searched the internet for similar problems but I haven't found anything yet. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I feel your pain. Did you ever solve the issue??!??!?!?! https://xkcd.com/979/

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. I have a function to catch uncaughtExceptions

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
  logger.fatal(`${(new Date()).toUTCString()}: uncaughtException: '${err.message}'. Stack Trace To Follow.`);
  logger.fatal(err.stack);
  process.exit(1);
});
```

That thing was killing node. There needs to be a check if you are in test or not, and if you are in test DONT catch the errors.